# Express.js don't set cookies on production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I've collided with issue in my server.js script. Here is the server.js code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const appPort = process.env.APP_PORT;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    var campaign = req.query.campaign;
    var click = req.query.param1;

    if (campaign !== undefined && click !== undefined)
    {
        res.cookie('campaign', campaign, { maxAge: 86400 * 1000 });
        res.cookie('click', click, { maxAge: 86400 * 1000 });
    }
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.get('/members', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/members.html'));

app.post('/members', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('firstName', req.body.firstname);
    res.cookie('email', req.body.email);

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/members.html');
});

app.listen(appPort, () => console.log(`App is running on ${appPort} port`));
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

I have to set cookies when the next request will come to a server:

> http://example.com/?campaign=28&param1=c4324

All work fine at my localhost, but when I transfer all changes to production server all work fine to, except a cookies, witch don't saving at the `app.get('/', (req, res)`. In other places (for example: `app.get('/members')` all work fine. Please help me.

Comment: Which production server are you using?

Comment: Digitalocean 8 GB Memory / 30 GB Disk / FRA1 - Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

Comment: Nginx? If yes, you might want to do something like: `add_header Set-Cookie "cip=$remote_addr;Domain=example.com;Path=/;Max-Age=100000";`

Comment: Ref: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/setting-cookies-in-nginx

Comment: A want to add some explanations. A cookies don't saving at the app.get('/', (req, res){} action. In other places (app.get('/members')) all work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in OS configuration, more precisely in access rights. 
I use digitalocean service, where I setup Ubuntu, Apache and other staff. When my app tried to create cookies, Ubuntu don't allow Apache default user to create it. When I allowed Apache user to write new files in my app directory the problem is solved.